# Dual boot and installing Ubuntu on F drive

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

Currently I have two hard disks:

1. Local Disk C (where Windows 7 is installed)
2. Linux F ( where I want to install Ubuntu)

[image: Disk]

I don't know which is my F Drive. I can't find the answer anywhere.

From what I have researched, people are doing Windows partitioning if they are going to use Linux on the same hard drive, so I assume I don't have to do Windows partitioning if I am going to use the whole F Drive for Ubuntu. Please correct me if I am wrong. This is how my Disk Management Looks:

[image: Disk Management]

I entered BIOS, boot from the USB and installed Ubuntu. I followed the installation steps, but I came to a halt at the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer. I chose the *Something else* option, then there was a dropdown menu, but I couldn't tell which disk was the F drive.

[image: Ubuntu Installation]
When I choose `/dev/sda` I get a `No root file system` error.

[image: No root file system]

Comment: Hey desh, can't you tell from the amount of storage?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the partition on the F drive, to obtain 230GB of "free space"? That way, when you start Linux installer, it'll offer to install your Linux distribution on this free space, format it the way it has to, etc... EDIT: that's provided there's indeed nothing on this drive and your computer doesn't boot on it...

Comment: I can , but F drive has around 1 partition and around 240GB and the Local Disk C has around 512GB. But In Linux it show dev/sda/1 or dev/sda . So that is why I am wondering is there a sure fire way to know

Comment: Why does the drive you want to install Linux to have a file system. This would be clear if that isn’t the case. Your screenshots clearly identify each physical disk.

Comment: When installing, you can leave alone the drive that says "Windows boot manager", that's where Windows is and you don't want to overwrite that just yet. My advice: in Windows, in Disk Management, right-click on the "Linux" drive, choose to delete the partition, confirm, and you'll have a well-sized free space to install Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using Windows Partioning to install Linux.

Just remove the volume in Windows and create the partition from free space in the Linux installer.

Your linux installer needs to reformat the partition anyway, because (as far as I know) your Linux won't run on a NTFS file system.

Comment: OK so what should I do?  Create a partition on the f drive?

Comment: No. (Sorry if I speak out of turn) You just leave the F drive as empty space, reboot your PC on your Linux installer medium (DVD, USB, I don't know), and when the time comes to choose where to install Linux, you'll find a 230+GB free space where to do it. Select that line, click on Next, and proceed with install. Please note that Ubuntu will install a bootloader of its own that will take precedence over Windows's. It means you'll have the choice on startup between Ubuntu (it'll probably set itself as default) and Windows. Prepare a USB Windows installer in case you don't like Ubuntu after all.

Comment: Actually what I want is a dual Boot alongside with Windows. That is exactly why I got another hard disk of 240GB. The last time  I installed linux alongside windows. It was a disaster , that My windows core files got corrupted.

Comment: Yeah, but this is still how you do it. Doesn't matter if it't two separate hard disks or just one...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution to it

1. I created a partition on my F disk by clicking on shrink disk and allocated around 100GB by going to Disk Management On Windows
2. Then I proceeded by Booting through My USB and went to linux installation.
3. Proceeded with Normal installation of Linux.
4. When it came to installation type, I choose 'Something else'.
5. I choose my 100GB of free space. I allocated some space for swap area, root and home.
6. For installation boot I choose /dev/sda
7. Installation proceeded  as Normal.

Comment: Glad it worked - that's what I meant except that I didn't know you only want to use a part of your *F disk* for Linux.

Comment: Ditto, but hey, as long as it works... :-)

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help

Comment: Anytime! Enjoy Ubuntu!